# importXML in Google Spreadsheets from YahooFinace

Tags: xml, import, google-sheets, yahoo-finance, parse-error

I want to import the *Beta* of a stock, e.g. the *Facebook* stock, from Yahoo Finance into a cell within a Google Spreadsheets document.

Here is the Facebook page in Yahoo Finance: **`http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=FB`**

Here is the XPath of the *Beta* element within that page: **`//*[@id="table1"]/tbody/tr[6]/td`**

(which I obtained using **Inspect element** within Google Chrome, then right-clicking on the element's code and clicking on *Copy Xpath*)

Thus in the Google Spreadsheet cell I am entering:

```
**=ImportXML("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=FB", "//*[@id="table1"]/tbody/tr[6]/td")**
```

However, I get: **#ERROR**, and when I hover over the cell I read: **error: Parse error**

My locale in Google Spreadsheets is set to US, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use " inside of other ". Have to replace inner " with '

=ImportXML("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=FB", "//*[@id='table1']/tbody/tr[6]/td")

Comment: I don't know if that's true but it only changes the type of error. Now I get **#N/A** and when I hover **The xPath query did not return any data**

Comment: You may have to do side reference like =ImportXML("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=FB", "//table[@id='table1']") and then work a bit with 6th column of the result, to extract the actual value.

Comment: you could also do something like =GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOGL","beta"), but for whatever mysterious reason, FB on Google Finance does not have valid beta value  :-(

Comment: **=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOGL","beta")**: Yes, it was what I tried to do first and unfortunately isn't available for FB.

I end up using **=index(ImportHTML("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=FB", "table", 2),6,2)**, as a second best.